# git log error "fatal: ambiguous argument'filename.sh' : unknown revision or path not in working tree"

Tags: git

git log is giving me an error "fatal: ambiguous argument'' : unknown revision or path not in working tree"

```
git log -1 --branch-name --date=format:"%Y-%m-%d" --pretty="~|%h|%an|%ad|%s|" filename
```

but the file exists in the release as well the feature branch. Also, It is showing me the revision when running the below command

```
git ls-tree -r <branchname>|grep -i <filename>--> displays me the blob SHA1 value
```

The issue doesn't occur If I execute the below command from the same branch then it is working fine.

```
git checkout branch-name
```

please suggest how can I do it in a Unix script and checkout the branch each time, as I want to get the below information by scanning many branches using the branch-name and file-name (or suggest any alternate way).

`commitID|author|date|commit-msg|`

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Try writing `--` before the filename: `git blahblah -- filename`

Comment: ... and depending on what you write, you might get results with grep and still not get results with git ls-tree. Say, you grep blah.txt, it will match some-directory/some-blah.txt, but `git ls-tree -r HEAD -- blah.txt` won't work... might have to provide `*blah.txt` instead.

Comment: Have modified the earlier query, Can someone please suggest.